# how to push all files in a folder to all git branches

Tags: git, directory, git-branch, git-push, remote-branch

I have a lot git branches.

There's a directory/folder in which I keep apk files.

But whenever I add a apk/file and push it
`(1. git add, 2. git commit -m "", 3. git push)`, 
It gets pushed to the local branch in which i'm working.

Instead of this I want to push that file to all branches, so how can I do that?

Also already in that folder there are lot of apk files which are present only for that particular branch.

So how can I make them available for all branch(i.e. push all those apk files to all branches)?

Comment: You don't push files. You push commits.   If you want to apply a commit from one branch on another, you can use cherry pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you commit into a branch, and push to a remote repo all your commits.

If you want that commit (assuming it only includes your new file) to be visible in all other branches, one way would be to **[`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)** that commit to the other branches.

If you just created that commit into `master`, you would switch branch and cherry-pick (the commit on top of) `master`:

```
git checkout another_branch
git cherry-pick master
```

However, this is not recommended if you intent to merge that other branch back to master at some point, as that would introduce a **[duplicate commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309)**.

To read -- much more -- on that topic, see "[git commit to all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461116/6309)".

Merging your current branch to other branches is better (see "[do a `git cherry-pick` in multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476881/6309)"), but not always possible/wanted, as it would merge all commits from one branch to the other.

An actual **proper solution** would simply be to **checkout** to another branch and **add** your file (again there), make a **commit** (again) there.
And **repeat** for the other branches.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Source Tree application, it is possible to push multiple branches at once.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/314016/push-to-multiple-remotes-with-sourcetree

Comment: will try using 'Source Tree application', i haven't used it before... BTW thanks for showing some hope :)

Comment: We need to keep our vocabulary clear here.  You add commits to branches, and then push to the remote repo.  Pushing multiple branches doesn't help you until you have committed the changes you want (e.g. the new files) to each branch.  I like the "cherry pick" suggestion made above by v3ga